# Function that uses define directive

Tags: c++, global, c-preprocessor

I have this piece of code which sends email via libcurl

```
#define FROM    "<my@gmail.com>"
#define TO      "<your@gmail.com>"

static const char *payload_text[] = {
  "To: " TO "\r\n",
  "From: " FROM "\r\n",
  "Subject: Shift\r\n",
  "text\r\n",
  NULL
};

struct upload_status {
  int lines_read;
};

static size_t payload_source(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
  struct upload_status *upload_ctx = (struct upload_status *)userp;
  const char *data;

  if((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size*nmemb) < 1)) {
    return 0;
  }

  data = payload_text[upload_ctx->lines_read];

  if(data) {
    size_t len = strlen(data);
    memcpy(ptr, data, len);
    upload_ctx->lines_read++;

    return len;
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
  struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;
  struct upload_status upload_ctx;

  upload_ctx.lines_read = 0;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "my@gmail.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "pass");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, (long)CURLUSESSL_ALL);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "google.pem");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, FROM);
    recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, TO);
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, "edgE0DF.tmp"); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload_ctx);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    curl_slist_free_all(recipients);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My question is: how can I make a function which takes as arguments from and to and change my global `FROM` and `TO`? Is this possible?  Because, I know that global variables are initialized before other parts of code and this means that my `static const char *payload_text[]` that uses `FROM` and `TO` will be initialized with wrong addresses.

Comment: If you change to make `FROM` and `TO` not be `#define`'d then you will also have to change the code in `payload_source` to have custom behaviour for those lines

Comment: but payload_text is const and i think this will be a problem

Comment: You are aware that `#define`s don't have addresses (they don't exist at runtime), right? They are substituted at compile-time, so, effectively, your `"To: " TO "\r\n", "From: " FROM "\r\n"` becomes `"To: " "<your@gmail.com>" "\r\n", "From: " "<my@gmail.com>" "\r\n"`, which is equivalent to `"To: <your@gmail.com>\r\n", "From: <my@gmail.com>\r\n"`.

Comment: @user3216932 It isn't a problem, I'm suggesting to not use `payload_text` for those two lines

Comment: You won't be able to modify `FROM` and `TO` in run-time, but `sprintf()` may be useful for what I guess you want to do.